# Where is the len function used in PyTorch Dataset?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I am looking to use the code from [here](https://github.com/nshaud/DeepNetsForEO/blob/master/SegNet_PyTorch_v2.ipynb) .
However, I am looking at box 5, where there is the following function;

```
def __len__(self):
    # Default epoch size is 10 000 samples
    return 10000
```

I do not see  anywhere throughout this script where this function is being used.
Clarification on this would be appreciated.

Also, I want to determine the number of image patches used for training  this convolutional neural network. Is this len function linked to the number of patches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a function of the [Dataset](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/data.html#torch.utils.data.Dataset) class. The `__len__()` function specifies the size of the dataset. In your referenced code, in box 10, a dataset is initialized and passed to a [DataLoader](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader) object:

```
train_set = ISPRS_dataset(train_ids, cache=CACHE)
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_set,batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
```

You see that in the `DataLoader` the dataset object is passed as well as the batch size. The DataLoader object then uses the `__len__` function of the Dataset to create the batches. This happens in box 13, where it is iterated over the DataLoader.

Comment: what does the `return 10000` represent?  Does it mean it loops through the data 10000 times?

Comment: It means that the dataset size (aka length) is 10000. Let's say you specify your batch size as 500, then you would have 20 iterations per epoch.